# Reading a file in Seattle Test Bed

Tags: python, file

Hi I have been having this problem whereI am trying to read a file in **Seattle Test Bed.** The code seems fine in normal command prompt but when I run the same in Seattle remotely it gives me an error of file not found:

```
   try:
     #myip=getmyip()
     myfileobject = open("output.txt","r")
     myfile=myfileobject.read()
     print myfile
   except IOError:
     print "not found"
```

Dont worry about indentation that is fine. Just the error in Seattle 
Exception (with type 'exceptions.IOError'): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output.txt'

Comment: Do you have the file "output.txt" and the script in the same directory?

Comment: yes  @A.Rodas It is in the same file dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways I got the solution, I forgot to upload the file to my nodes in Seattle. Hence had to first upload the file then run the command.